# Error 1 error A1000: cannot open file : \masm32\includes\masm32rt.inc

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2012, masm, masm32

I'm trying to setup a assembler program in VS2012, but whenever `include masm32\includes\masm32rt.inc` gets called it returns that error.

If I use the absolute path, it works, but all the includes use `masm32\includes\` as their incudepath.

Is there a way to set \masm32 on the environment variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "the absolute path... works"? A path beginning with a backslash is already an absolute path.

Comment: I mean that `D:\masm32\includes\masm32rt.inc` works.

Comment: Despite its name, MASM32 isn't part of Visual Studio, but an [entirely separate library](http://www.masm32.com/).

Comment: Yes it is, I installed it on `D:\masm32` but all the example source code and all the defalt includes `.inc` reference the folder as `\masm32`, but then I get that error `connot open file`. So I guess something  isn't configured correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MASM32 is **NOT** part of Visual Studio, MASM is.

If you have MASM32 installed on one drive, but your projects/sources are on another drive, how can a relative path work????  i.e. `include masm32\includes`  If this is the case, then you have to use absolute paths, i.e. `D:\masm32\includes\masm32rt.inc`

I do not use VS, but it should have an option to set the include path, which it will then pass this path to the command line of ml to search for includes.